# setting up a launchpad ppa: "bzr builddeb" fails

Tags: ubuntu, bazaar, launchpad

i'm trying to setup a ppa for a library that i am writing. I've spent a couple of days now and slowly move forward, but now it seems i am stuck with an error because "bzr builddeb" cannot find the debian/changelog file.

My debian control files are in the following directory:

```
foo-ppa/trunk/foo/debian
```

When i run 'dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S' then everything works fine.
But when i run "bzr builddep -S" then i get the following error:

```
Building using working tree
bzr: ERROR: Could not find changelog at /home/chris/prj/foo-ppa/trunk/debian/changelog in tree.
```

I understand that my directory structure is "wrong" (trunk/foo/debian instead of trunk/debian). But when i change the directory structure (using trunk/debian) then "bzr builddep -- -nc -us -uc" complains about the new path and returns the following error:

```
bzr: ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/chris/prj/foo-ppa/trunk/foo/debian/README.Debian'
```

The file exists, but it's in trunk/debian instead of trunk/foo/debian.

How do I have to set up the directories in order to get bzr and dpkg-buildpackage working?

Thanks
Christoph

-------------- edit:

i managed to fix this by removing the build-area directory and retrying a few times. I do not know what exactly was the problem, but it's working now.

Comment: admin - feel free to close this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the second command, but run "bzr rm" (no arguments) first. This will mark all of the files that have disappeared as removed in bazaar, and will prevent bzr-builddeb from printing that error.